# Download txt file from Github?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I'm trying to download a txt file from github that contains common passwords (after each password there's a new line), whenever i view the raw and right click and save as a text file, it all gets jumbled up with no new lines whatsoever, it's all jumbled up as one word. How can i download from github without getting this error? Thanks!

Comment: download all sources as zip

Comment: Are you opening the file with Notepad? If that's so, it's because Windows has got a slightly different newline characters (CR + LF) instead of LF

Comment: Most likely the file uses Linux `\n` new lines and not Windows new lines `\r\n`. Try using Notepad++ or something similar

Comment: @MaximilianPeters you're right on the spot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`tr` worked fine for me

```sh
cat jumpledup_list.txt | tr " " "\n" > tidy_list.txt
```